# How to accommodate vendor prefixes in my JQuery for Off Canvas Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cross-browser

I can't seem to get this code to work in all browsers. I can get it to work in either Chrome or Firefox when I remove one of the vendor prefixes, but I want it to work across all browsers. My code is as follows:
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

```
    var menu = "close";

    $('.menu-toggle').click(function() {

        if (menu == "close") {
            $('.navbar').css('-moz-transform','translate(0, 0)','-webkit-transform', 'translate(-100%, 0)');  //opens up off canvas menu
            menu = "open";
            $('.site-overlay').show(); //opens overlay all the way uppp
        } else {
            $('.navbar').css('-moz-transform','translate(-100%, 0)','-webkit-transform', 'translate(-100%, 0)');  //closes off canvas menu
            menu = "close";
            $('.site-overlay').hide(); //closes overlay
        }
    });  
    $('.site-overlay').click(function() {
        $('.navbar').css('-moz-transform','translate(-100%, 0)','-webkit-transform', 'translate(-100%, 0)');
        menu = "close";
        $('.site-overlay').hide(); //closes overlay all the way closed
    });
});
```

Anyway to modify this to work in all browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When adding multiple css rules, you should do it like this:

```
$('.navbar').css({
    '-moz-transform':'translate(0, 0)',
    '-webkit-transform':'translate(-100%, 0)'
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Claudio Barreira

Comment: Doesn't jQuery v1.8 and more automatically handles vendor prefixes for you? Using `transform` is sufficient.